# How do I make my MongoDB query more efficient?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

Right now, I'm doing 2 steps. I want to eliminate one of them.

```
//Get total results, before the limit. I need this number for pagination reasons.
total_rooms = db.rooms.find({'name':'big'}).count();

//Get the actual results
rooms = db.rooms.find({'name':'big'}).skip(start).limit(num)
```

I'm doing double queries everywhere around my website, and I feel really silly. Mysql only requires me to do one query, and gives me the total_results.

Comment: if you want number of pages you can't eliminate any of those queries. even if you can combine it somehow - database will still perform same number of operations internally.

Comment: Thanks keymone. Is the first query very intensive? (better question: how intensive is it compared to the 2nd query)?

Comment: Don't worry about it. Issuing multiple queries is fine as long as they're fast. Make sure you have an index on 'name'. You can remove the need to get a count by switching from pagination to a "show more", twitter-style list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one query. Try this in the shell :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) db.test.save({a:i})
cursor = db.test.find().skip(10).limit(10)
```

Now, you can get the total result set size :

```
cursor.count()
1000
```

And the result set size taking skip and limit into account :

```
cursor.count(true)
10
```

Note that the server will do all the work needed to determine both numbers and a new count query will be issued if there is more data available on the server than was returned with the first results. In other words, cleaner code but not always more performance.

Comment: So, the performance is the same as executing the two queries?

Comment: It will always be as fast or faster than two queries. Exact performance depends on whether or not the server sent all result data or just the first batch. In the latter case cursor.count() will require an additional command to be sent to the server.

Comment: I'm using this method. thanks a lot.  Oh one last thing---if I have "sort" along with the skip and limit (in cursor)...that wouldn't affect running the count()...right?